# Get key of array with indexPath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table, when I select a row I execute this command:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


     InfoClienteViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoClienteViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:infoViewController animated:YES];

     [infoViewController setIdt:idt[indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"You Select -> %zd",idt[indexPath.row]);

}
```

In my array (idt) I have this values:

1. [0] -> 2
2. [1] -> 3
3. [2] -> 4

So, when I click in the first row on my table (Now the indexPath.row is [0] ),  the NSLog was to show the number 2, but return the number 4451524096, why? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays can't hold plain numbers (primitive data types like `int`, `float`, `NSInteger`, ...), they can only hold objects. So, when you log `idt[indexPath.row]` as a plain number you get gibberish.

Your log should be:

```
NSLog(@"You Select -> %@", idt[indexPath.row]);
```

to properly log the object.

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains int or integer value then you need to access like this below. But make sure that your array contains all the int values.

//For int data types access it like this

```
NSLog(@"You Select -> %d", idt[indexPath.row].intValue);
```

//For integer data types access it like this

```
NSLog(@"You Select -> %ld", idt[indexPath.row].integerValue);
```